# read_excel () and lapply()

Tags: r, lapply, readxl

I have a `.xlsx` file has two sheets and I want to  generate a list of both excel sheets using `read_excel` from `readxl` package . I have used this code

```
my_work <- lapply(excel_sheets("data.xlsx"), 
                      read_excel, 
                      path = "data.xlsx")
```

The `read_excel()` function is called multiple times on the `"data.xlsx"` file and each sheet is loaded in one after the other. The result is a list of data frames, each data frame representing one of the sheets in `data.xlsx`.
My question is ,  why should I  write the path argument in `lapply`function , since the file is already in the working directory ?

Comment: Because it is required by both functions `excel_sheets` and `read_excel`, no?

Comment: `read_excel` would otherwise have no idea where to look, since you only pass sheet names to `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation:

```
read_excel(path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

The parameter path is a required argument. So you need to fill it in. Otherwise, an error will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the easiest way but you can create a short function modifying the `read_excel()` function to take in both a sheet name parameter and path, then `lapply` over that function.

```
library(readxl)
path <- "data.xlsx"
sheet_names <- excel_sheets(path)

# create function
read_excel_sheet <- function(sheet_name, path) {
  x <- read_excel(path = path, sheet = sheet_name)
}

my_work <- lapply(sheet_names, read_excel_sheet, path = path)
```