# Iteratively read, manipulate multiple excel files and append them into one dataframe using R

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, readxl

Under a directory, I have multiple excel files with similar format (you may download sample files from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho3visres55kpoy/test.zip?dl=0)):

[image]

I will need to

1. loop files and `read_excel()`,
2. mutate a new column `name` with second column name,
3. rename the first and the second column to `date` and `value` respectively, remove last column (whose original column name is `1`);
4. append all dfs to one dataframe using `do.call(rbind, df.list)`

[image]

**What I have done:**

To loop and get files paths:

```
library(fs)
folder_path <- './test/'
file_paths <- dir_ls(folder_path, regexp = ".xlsx")
```

Function to read excels:

```
read_excel_file <- function(path) {
  df <- read_excel(path = path, header = TRUE)
}
```

lapply `read_excel()` function to each excel file:

```
df.list = lapply(file_paths, function(file) read_excel(file, skip = 2, col_names = FALSE))
df <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

The expected result will be a dataframe like this:

```
         date  value    name
2  2021-01-07  -76.5 J05-J01
3  2021-01-08  -93.5 J05-J01
4  2021-01-15   -305 J05-J01
5  2021-01-22    289 J05-J01
6  2021-01-29  242.5 J05-J01
7  2021-02-05    266 J05-J01
8  2021-02-10  239.5 J05-J01
9  2021-02-19  305.5 J05-J01
10 2021-01-07    323 J01-J09
11 2021-01-08  317.5 J01-J09
12 2021-01-15  527.5 J01-J09
13 2021-01-22    -51 J01-J09
14 2021-01-29  -58.5 J01-J09
15 2021-02-05    -76 J01-J09
16 2021-01-07   76.5 J01-J05
17 2021-01-08   93.5 J01-J05
18 2021-01-15    305 J01-J05
19 2021-01-22   -289 J01-J05
20 2021-01-29 -242.5 J01-J05
21 2021-02-05   -266 J01-J05
22 2021-02-10 -239.5 J01-J05
```

How could I achieve that using R? Thanks a lot at advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(fs)
library(readxl)

file_paths = list.files("./test/", pattern = "*.xlsx")

df = data.frame()

for(i in file_paths){
  df_temp = read_xlsx(path=paste0("./test/", i))
  df_temp$`1` = names(df_temp)[2]
  names(df_temp) = c("date", "value", "name")
  df = rbind(df, df_temp)
}

rm(df_temp)
```

---

**Output:**

```
> df
# A tibble: 21 x 3
   date                 value name   
   <dttm>               <dbl> <chr>  
 1 2021-01-07 00:00:00   76.5 J01-J05
 2 2021-01-08 00:00:00   93.5 J01-J05
 3 2021-01-15 00:00:00  305   J01-J05
 4 2021-01-22 00:00:00 -289   J01-J05
 5 2021-01-29 00:00:00 -242.  J01-J05
 6 2021-02-05 00:00:00 -266   J01-J05
 7 2021-02-10 00:00:00 -240.  J01-J05
 8 2021-01-07 00:00:00  323   J01-J09
 9 2021-01-08 00:00:00  318.  J01-J09
10 2021-01-15 00:00:00  528.  J01-J09
# ... with 11 more rows
```

---

**Update**, with function:

```
read_excel = function(name) {
  df_temp = read_xlsx(path=paste0("./test/", name))
  df_temp$`1` = names(df_temp)[2]
  names(df_temp) = c("date", "value", "name")
  return(df_temp)
}


df = do.call(rbind, lapply(file_paths, read_excel))
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Sorry, I have one extra question, is it possible to do so by write a function to read and manipulate excel files, then use `lapply()`? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669772/read-excel-and-lapply

Comment: I've add the same logic as function, see "update"

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

files <- list.files()

combined <- bind_rows(
  lapply(
    files,
    function(f) {
      df <- read_xlsx(f) 
      df %>%
        select(date = 1, value = 2) %>%
        mutate(name = colnames(df)[2])
    }
  ) 
)
```

**Alternative by @ah bon:**

```
read_file <- function(file) {
  df <- read_xlsx(file) 
  df <- df %>%
    select(date = 1, price = 2) %>%
    mutate(name = colnames(df)[2])
  return(df)
}

df <- bind_rows(
  lapply(
    files,
    read_file
  ) 
)

# or `df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read_file))`
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, maybe it's better we set `function(f)` outside of `combined`?

Comment: Feel free to choose whatever works best for you, that shouldn't matter in terms of performance.